# how to find empty block using regular expression in java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to find unused if statements in my projects. So i wrote a sample program for find if statements but it has some issues. Please find below test file and source file for finding unsued if statements

This is sample java file for testing

```
//test file

 public class SearchClass {

private void test() {

    if(true) {
        if(true) {

        }
    }

      if(true) {
         //kavi
          //kamal
          //kamal
      }

      if(true) {
          //kavi
          //kamal
      } 

      if(true) {

        } 

      if(true){
            /*fsdsddgd
            ddgdgdfg
            gdfgdgdfg*/
            System.out.println("");
            /*gdfgdfg
            fgdfgfg*/
        }

      if(true) {
          /*fsdsddgd
            ddgdgdfg
            gdfgdgdfg*/
      }

                        if(true) {
            /*              fsdsddgd
                            ddgdgdfg
                           gdfgdgdfg
                           gdfgdfg
                           fgdfgfg

        */              System.out.println("kamal");
         }

 }
 }
```

From the above,  i am not able to clean all unused if statements. So please do need full.

```
       //sample program
             import java.io.IOException;
              import java.io.StringReader;
              import java.nio.charset.Charset;
              import java.nio.file.Files;
              import java.nio.file.Paths;
              import java.util.regex.Matcher;
              import java.util.regex.Pattern;

 public class EmptyBlockCleaner {

  private static String text;

public static final String EMPTY_IF_BLOCK_REEXP = "((if[\\s]*\\([^\\)]*\\)[\\s]*\\{[\\s]*})(.+?))" ;

public static final String IF_BLOCK_MULTIPLE_LINE = "((if[\\s]*\\([^\\)]*\\)[\\s]*\\{((/\\*(.|[\\r\\n])*?\\*/)|\\s)*\\})(.+?))";



private String getFileAsString( String file ) throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file));
    return new String(encoded, Charset.defaultCharset());

}

private boolean isEmptyBlockWithoutComments(String file) throws IOException {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(IF_BLOCK_MULTIPLE_LINE, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    text = getFileAsString(file);
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(text); 
     while (matcher.find()) {
        String javaCode = removeComments(matcher.group());
        Pattern innerPattern = Pattern.compile(EMPTY_IF_BLOCK_REEXP, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher innerMatcher = innerPattern.matcher(javaCode); 
        while (innerMatcher.find()) {
            text = matcher.replaceAll("");
            System.out.println(text);
        }

    }

    return false;
}

private String removeComments(String code) {
    StringBuilder newCode = new StringBuilder();
    try (StringReader sr = new StringReader(code)) {
        boolean inBlockComment = false;
        boolean inLineComment = false;
        boolean out = true;

        int prev = sr.read();
        int cur;
        for(cur = sr.read(); cur != -1; cur = sr.read()) {
            if(inBlockComment) {
                if (prev == '*' && cur == '/') {
                    inBlockComment = false;
                    out = false;
                }
            } else if (inLineComment) {
                if (cur == '\r') {
                    sr.mark(1);
                    int next = sr.read();
                    if (next != '\n') {
                        sr.reset();
                    }
                    inLineComment = false;
                    out = false; 
                } else if (cur == '\n') {
                    inLineComment = false;
                    out = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (prev == '/' && cur == '*') {
                    sr.mark(1); 
                    int next = sr.read();
                    if (next != '*') {
                        inBlockComment = true;
                    }
                    sr.reset(); 
                } else if (prev == '/' && cur == '/') {
                    inLineComment = true;
                } else if (out){
                    newCode.append((char)prev);
                } else {
                    out = true;
                }
            }
            prev = cur;
        }
        if (prev != -1 && out && !inLineComment) {
            newCode.append((char)prev);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newCode.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    EmptyBlockCleaner blockCleaner = new EmptyBlockCleaner();
    blockCleaner.isEmptyBlockWithoutComments("path");

}
```

}

Comment: That's what analyzers in IDEs are for.

Comment: An unused statement might have comments that include more `{braces}`... A nightmare for regex.

Comment: Do you understand that this task is MUCH more complicated than trivial parser. Nobody writes statements like `if(true)` in real life since such statements have no sense. There are a lot of tools for static and dynamic code analysis. Such a trivial things like unreachable code are caught by compiler.

Comment: Then how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find unused if statements in my projects

Use [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) or [intellij inspections](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_inspection.html), or just doing an auto format in whatever ide you use will catch these basic unused blocks.  Assuming you use eclipse/netbeans/intellij it will work.

Don't roll yr own regex based "solution".

Comment: I know lot of tools available for finding code style but has not any replacement option for that. only all are find bug. Then we have to fix manually. But i am creating a tool for replacing too if it find empty block etc..

Comment: @KaviK no, lots of them enable you to specifiy replacement options.

Comment: Can you please give in detail or any tutorial?

Comment: Just use any of the big ide's netbeans/eclipse/intellij

Comment: Am using checkstyle in eclipse kepler and go through option if any replacement option exists but there is no option for replacement... Sorry if I asked silly question....